# SharePoint List Gets Deleted automatically

Tags: list

Created a list & its fields programmatically using JavaScript. Could view, but after a while, when I searched in the site contents. Later I added few items using REST which were successfully added.

The same code when run the next day gave me error ! When the list was searched it was not existing! So recreated and then added items.

Could anyone suggest why this inconsistency?

Comment: Do you have any code of deleting items from list?

Comment: SharePoint Lists get deleted by users or automated processes users created, find all users who can do that to your list and one will have done it.

Comment: I neither have a delete-items code nor anyone else have access to the list!

Comment: Check in Recycle Bin, you should find the deleted list instance there along with the person who did it.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find it in Recycle bin either. May be because the list definition was created inside My Visual Studio!

Comment: One finding was when i try to insert a date value ( using datepicker) into that list it gives an error. When checked again with the list - found that the list is again deleted! Though its weird would like to know the reason !

Comment: Maybe you should try to figure out if there was any change in your site. Or did anyone deploy any solution to this site?

Answer (score 1):

You stated in a comment that you are working with Visual Studio, and that the list is created from a list definition/instance.
I also assume that the list is disappearing after you return to the project and deploy the solution again.

If that is the case, then probably your problem is that visual studio is performing automatic conflict resolution when the new version of your solution is deployed, and since it finds a list with the same name of an instance in the solution it "silently" deletes the one on the site. You should get a message about it in the output windows, but it is pretty easy to miss. That means that the list won't get recreated until the corresponding feature is reactivated.

Notice that this may also happen if you use the **F5** deploy&debug from inside VS. I admit I may be wrong - I almost never use it, I prefer to attach to SharePoint processes manually - but I think that if you use F5 Visual Studio may perform automated cleanup as soon as the debug session ends (as opposed to performing it only when you redeploy the solution).

---

**ADD ON**: 
If this is indeed your case, you should be able to workaround this behavior by selecting the list instance in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer view, and then under its property setting `Deployment Conflict Resolution: None` switch. Just remember that by doing that the list won't get destroyed but also won't get recreated updated if you should change it structure - proceed with caution.

Comment: You were exactly correct. Its the same scenario. I first wrote code to create the list and its fields from my code , pressed F5 tested and then proceeded to create a form to insert an item into it. Now when i try to insert an item pressing F5again it fails and found the list no more exists!

Comment: What is the corresponding feature to be activated?  Any solution to it ?

Comment: See the edit. I hope that is the setting you need